# Something to look forward to?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

> 88 = 5 = 1
>   90 = 4-7 = 2
>   95 = 1-10 = 2
>   02 = 9-12 = 2
>   09 = 2-3-11 = 3
>   10 = 8 = 1
>   12 = 1-4-7 = 3
>   17 = ?

What is the missing info about?

Comment: @boboquack 90 is correct. It is an enigmatic puzzle so although the puzzle is not hard, finding what the puzzle is about is the hard thing. I can however say that your current approach to the puzzle will not lead you to the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 17 = 1-10 = 2

Explanation:

> There are two months in 2017 with a Friday the 13th: January and October.

Comment: +1 very good observation! Might I ask why you chose that as the important common detail? I could say they all have the 2nd on a monday and a 3rd on tuesday. Isn't there something more interesting in common? ;P

Comment: Perhaps the common characteristic is months whose first week fills up the first line, or months whose first day is in the upper left corner. This gives them a special geometric appearance.

Comment: @stackreader I just thought it's generally a nice thing to get the first day of a month off. That's what your title seemed to suggest. Perhaps wildBillMunson's reasoning is the correct one, at least in the American calendar (which I was not familiar with until I read his comment).

Comment: @stackreader Oh, I think I got it now.

Comment: Good job! That's the one. The question mark in the title was to show that it is not likely that many people are looking forward to those.